# Do people remember similar questions or do they actually search for duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, behavior

I am surprised by the number of questions flagged as duplicate. Being curious, do people actually remember similar questions (I know some do) or do they actually go the extra mile, searching for possible duplicates, all this so they can post a comment about duplicates?

The question of course is about the second part and targeted to people who practice it.

Comment: Note that most comments about possible duplicates are also autogenerated by when someone actually votes to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 13):

For me, two possibilities:

1. I remember seeing some question like it

   1a. use Google to find the older one.
2. I think to myself, "there is **no** way this has never been asked before". See 1a.

Comment: If only more people would think to themselves, "there is **no** way this has never been asked before".  :)

Comment: It always amazes me that some people are totally missing the capacity for #2 -- they ask a very common question and are astonished when it is closed as a dupe, or more extremely, handed a "did you even bother googling for this first" response.

Comment: Site search works too. Haven't used anything but it in finding dupes.

Comment: And there is a right column that lists "Related".
By looking at it, you may identify some similar titles.

Answer (score 7):

Rex gets most cases, but there are also:

- **I** already answered (or once, asked) that questions so I go and find the dupe in my profile listing or using the `user:me` search operator
- A few are so frequently duplicated that I recall the either the exact title or in the most extreme cases the *sequence number* of the primordial version.

Comment: +1. Whenever I see regex and html together in a title, I type xhtml to my address bar and Firefox happily gives THE answer - even Firefox knows you shouldn't parse html with regex.

Answer (score 2):

The "Related" posts list invariably lists the duplicate high up.